# Xcode 12.5.1 Can't add apple account

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos-big-sur

I'm trying to add an apple account on Xcode 12.5.1 but it always showing an error. My current os is Big Sur 11.3. I tried restarting the xcode and also the mac but same result.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue you mentioned began in Big Sur. It has been examined widely on GitHub.
https://github.com/XVimProject/XVim2/issues/340

Also you can try running below commands in Terminal:

- $ xcrun git config --global user.name "Your name"
- $ xcrun git config --global user.email your.email@example.com

After that restart Xcode. Hope it will help you out.